# Set form field value of MS Word document in PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-word

I have a word template file where i defined some form fields. I want to update the value of these form fields programmatically using PHP.

I did some R&D and find the phpWord library but its does not have option to update the form field. I have also tried to use ASpose word cloud api but its api is not working for update the form fields.

Can anybody provide me any plugin or api for update the form field value.